# Read file from serial port using Java

Tags: java, serial-port

I'm begginner in Java, I'm writing `("FLASH").getbytes()` like this to `serialport`.

After I'll get `FLASH_OK` as response, again I've to send file request. After that I'll get response as `FILE_OK` then I have read file up to end of the file.

I'm not getting how to do this, so please help me.

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 8):

[**jSSC**](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/) is a stable serial IO java library, take a look at following [examples](http://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wiki/jSSC_examples):

- writing data to serial port
- reading data from serial port

Answer (score 3):

Looks like to need a **[`SerialPortReader`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid3870A59B6C87B047751FC843024AAF0C4D60E1E5.aspx?s=getbytes+serialport+ok#L110)** which needs to implement a `SerialPortEventListener`

```
     public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
     {
            case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[40];

            try
            {
                while (inputStream.available() > 0)
                {
                    int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                }
                System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("DTR: " + serialPort.isDTR());
                System.out.println("DSR: " + serialPort.isDSR());
                System.out.println("CTS: " + serialPort.isCTS());
                System.out.println("RTS: " + serialPort.isRTS());
                System.out.println();
                outputStream.write("ACTIVESYNC".getBytes());
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```