# How to send data to COM PORT using JAVA?

Tags: java, serial-port

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Serial Communication on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows)

Friends,
I want to connect and transfer data to COM PORT (either virtual or original) in JAVA?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This question has been asked and answered many times:

[Read file from serial port using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544824/read-file-from-serial-port-java)

[Reading serial port in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336714/reading-serial-port-in-java)

[Reading file from serial port in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560328/reading-file-from-serial-port-in-java)

[Is there Java library or framework for accessing Serial ports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747539/is-there-java-library-or-framework-for-accessing-serial-ports)

[Java Serial Communication on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264277/java-serial-communication-on-windows)

to reference a few.

Personally I recommend SerialPort from http://serialio.com - <strike>it's not free, but it's well worth the developer (no royalties) licensing fee for any commercial project</strike>. Sadly, it is no longer royalty free to deploy, and SerialIO.com seems to have remade themselves as a hardware seller; I had to search for information on SerialPort.

From personal experience, I strongly recommend **against** the Sun, IBM and RxTx implementations, all of which were unstable in 24/7 use.  Refer to my answers on some of the aforementioned questions for details. To be perfectly fair, RxTx may have come a long way since I tried it, though the Sun and IBM implementations were essentially abandoned, even back then.

A newer free option that looks promising and may be worth trying is [jSSC (Java Simple Serial Connector)](https://code.google.com/p/java-simple-serial-connector/), as suggested by @Jodes comment.

Comment: A quick to note to others: if you were looking for a FREE way to use the serial port do not click the link. You are wasting your time.

Comment: jSSC (Java Simple Serial Connector) is free,  and I have found it extremely easy to use, and stable. Its developer is also very helpful. Highly recommended.

Comment: It appears that serialio.com does charge a distribution fee (royalty) for commercial products - and a rather steep one at that!

Comment: @KeithL: So it seems. They changed that since I used it years ago. Clearly, they felt they weren't being adequately compensated. Sad, really, it was, and presumably still is a best-in-class product.

Answer (score 7):

The Java Communications API (also known as javax.comm) provides applications access to RS-232 hardware (serial ports): http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `javax.comm` is the [`rxtx`](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/) library which supports more platforms than `javax.comm`.

Comment: `Java Communications API` is just that - an API. Sun reference implementation is very limited, but [SerialIO SerialPort](http://serialio.com/products/serialport/serialport.php) (an enterprise grade solution) does implement `Java Communications API`

Comment: I understand that rxtx is an implementation of javax.comm

Comment: I've written an article about how to connect to a serial port using rxt, check it out: 
 https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/integrate-weighing-scales-using-rxtx-library-dantas-de-oliveira/