# java api to send file through serial port

Tags: java, file, serial-port, send

I want to send a file from my PC to a remote device connected through serial port. So is there any API in java to send file over serial port?

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times. see links/comments in the following stack overflow question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/900950/how-to-send-data-to-com-port-using-java

Answer (score 4):

checkout [javax.comm](http://java.sun.com/products/javacomm/reference/api/javax/comm/package-summary.html)

Comment: I checked it. but there is nothing

Comment: au contraire - there is a lot. But you've missed it :)

Answer (score 2):

See also [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/). It is [widely used](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Projects) and includes straightforward [examples](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Examples).

Comment: I have used the javacomm library. so if its possible through RXTX also it will be difficult for me to implement it.

Comment: It is part of several projects I use. I've add some links above, so you can judge for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [JPeripheral](http://code.google.com/p/jperipheral/).