# Send command to device with Java

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface, javax.comm

I want to connect magnetic card reader, send commands and get responses with Java (COM Port) in Windows XP. I have `.h` file & `dll`. I want use `dll` functions. How can I connect or send device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java api to send file through serial port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003821/java-api-to-send-file-through-serial-port)

Comment: @trashgod, I want send command and RECEIVE responses, not send file

Comment: @trashgod, but the DLL probably has high level functions specific for his reader which he would be missing in those libraries.

Comment: Ah, I see; now it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use JNI (Java Native Interface), google it for details. You probably will have to write some wrappers around the DLL in C first before JNI can use it.

Comment: +1. Can I solve my problem with Java APIs (Javax.comm or RXTX, not using JNI or write some code in C)?

Comment: @totali: I found @Eelke's comment and answer very helpful; I've clarified your question and up-voted the answer accordingly. When you have sufficient reputation, I urge you to do likewise. You may also want to review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @totali: using JNA as trashgod suggest in his answer shouldn't require any C but I have no experience with it. If you know the full serial protocol you can use any serial java communication library, see trashgods earlier comments.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you may be able to bind to the `dll` using [JNA](http://jna.java.net/).