# How can I Access COM Port in JAVA

Tags: java, sms

I need to make an SMS transceiver that automatically inputs to a database every SMS that it receives. I am using a USB GSM Modem and able to use AT commands via HyperTerminal at COM Port 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The official API from sun/oracle for communication with serial/parallel ports is the Java Communication API ( www.oracle.com slash technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html ).

Be aware: this api just contains Java interfaces - no implementation classes. Sun/oracle suggests to use the rxtx library as implementation (licensed as LGPL).

I have been using the rxtx library successfully. The official webpage is not looking promising, but the implementation works fine for serial and parallel ports:
http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/). It is Java library for interacting with GSM Devices. It should save you some time.

If this is not what you are looking for, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900950/how-to-send-data-to-com-port-using-java).

Comment: +1 Although technically not answering the question the OP *asked*, it's still useful.

Comment: I posted a link to a previous SO question for that reason. I used SMSLib in a project... for my case, it was better than using AT Commands, so I think that the OP will find it better than using AT commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use lib then write your code in cpp and use JNA or JNI to invoke the function. Third party libaray depends on hardware, I am not sure these will behave well.