# Java com port problem

Tags: java, gps, serial-port

I am trying to read some data of GPS from COM1 port. I have to show a message that the device is not connected if the gps device is not attached with the com port. I am using rxtxComm.jar, rxtxSerial.dll, gpsinput.jar in my project.

I am also facing problem from reading GPS data from com port.In my input stream no data is coming but the gps device is throughing data at the com port (I checked it by using hyper terminal).

code

Comment: Are you connecting via the com port (using javax.comm) or via USB using a java/USB API?

Comment: Down voters: please give this (brand new) user a chance to update this question before down voting it to oblivion. Otherwise you are driving people away from this community.

Comment: he probably missed to paste the code. he probably would come back and post it

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this.

[How to send data to COM PORT using JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900950/how-to-send-data-to-com-port-using-java)